# Could not load "jingle_peerconnection_so" native Android webRTC

Tags: android, eclipse, webrtc, libjingle

I am building an android application where my app user can do video chat with browser based user. For that, I have followed instruction on this [link](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/). But I think documentation on this link is very old.

So I checkout webRTC source code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/checkout) which is from Google repository. After that I have copied "talk" android sample example into my Eclipse workspace and run it. But I am getting error as "Could not load jingle_peerconnection_so".

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. You need to provide more information to allow people to give you a clear answer.

If you follow the guide on http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android, you will be able to build the app.

I've got the same error when I tried to deploy on the emulator (kitkat version). But if I deploy the app on my device (Android 4.1), it's work perfectly. 
So, in order to solve your problem (if it's really that), try to use your android device and not the emulator. 
Sorry but I don't know why isn't working on the emulator.